# Oracle- getting rows from a query which is not present in another query

Tags: sql, oracle

Lets say i have two queries::

*query 1:*

```
SELECT id, name, permission FROM table1
```

*result 1:*

```
+----+------+------------+
| id | name | permission |
+----+------+------------+
|  1 | A    | z          |
|  1 | A    | x          |
|  2 | B    | t          |
|  3 | C    | r          |
+----+------+------------+
```

*query 2:*

```
SELECT id, name, permission FROM table2
```

*result 2:*

```
+----+------+------------+
| id | name | permission |
+----+------+------------+
|  1 | A    | z          |
|  2 | B    | t          |
+----+------+------------+
```

I want the missing permissions as output:

```
+----+------+------------+
| id | name | permission |
+----+------+------------+
|  1 | A    | x          |
|  3 | C    | r          |
+----+------+------------+
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

Use the **MINUS** operator in ORACLE, it will give you all rows from the first table which are not in second, i.e. excluding mutual rows:

```
SELECT id, 
       name, 
       permission 
FROM   table1 
MINUS 
SELECT id, 
       name, 
       permission 
FROM   table2;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   table1 
WHERE  ( id, name, permission ) NOT IN (SELECT id, 
                                               name, 
                                               permission 
                                        FROM   table2);
```

Comment: NOT IN might be unsafe if any of the columns is nullable.

Answer (score 0):

This one is NULL safe:

```
SELECT 
   t1.id
   , t1.name
   , t1.permission 
FROM table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
   SELECT 1 
   FROM table2 t2
   WHERE 
      t1.id = t2.id
      AND t1.name = t2.name
      AND t1.permission = t2.permission
)
```